# Oracle UTL_FILE exceptions alternatives in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, amazon-aurora, postgresql-11, orafce

I'm migrating an Oracle stored procedure to AWS Aurora Postgres which has `UTL_FILE` operations to read and write in external files. In the Exception part, I have all these exception types used.
`UTL_FILE.invalid_path`, `UTL_FILE.invalid_operation`, `UTL_FILE.invalid_mode`, `UTL_FILE.read_error`, `UTL_FILE.write_error`, and `WHEN OTHERS`.

Is it possible to handle all these exceptions in Postgres or should I go for `orafce` extension?

Comment: I don't know AWS Aurora Postgres in detail, but it should be Postgres with different storage. If Aurora Postgres has UTL_FILE, then very probably it is from preinstalled Orafce extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I know, The AWS Aurora Postgres uses Orafce too

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/amazon-aurora-supports-postgresql-versions-117-1012-and-9617-and-adds-global-database-for-postgresql-117/

Postgres has not custom named exceptions like Oracle, so you have to rewrite your code little bit, you have to check error message instead - for example - Oracle's `UTL_FILE.write_error` is a Postgres's RAISE exception (named `raise_exception` - [P0001](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html)) with error message (available in `SQLERRM` variable or via `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS`) is [`"UTL_FILE_WRITE_ERROR"`](https://github.com/orafce/orafce/blob/master/file.c).